# How to get the root in an XML file using C

Tags: c, xml

Hi my homework is to build an xml parser using c. I am stuck at how to find the root of an xml file and also should check that the closing tag of the root is in the xml file.

Comment: Are you using some XML library like TinyXML? Or do you have to parse the file all by yourself?

Comment: I have to parse it all by myself :(

Comment: do you get to use a parser generator (like lex/yacc)?

Comment: When you say "find the root", the problem that you have is that you don't know how to recognize the root element, just the root? Can you parse the other elements without problems?

Comment: Do you know what the root is, its meaning?

Comment: Show us what your code so far... It'll make it a lot easier for us to give you relevant hints.

Comment: Actually I have completed the code upto ignoring the header line and the comment lines. I read the file by line to line and i stored it in the form an array, for instance word[1].. gives the line number 2 of the file. Then my plan is to analyze the strings(lines) one by one and check whether they follow the xml syntax.The problem is I am not able to get the logic of how to compare the opening and closing tags. Also I am not able to identify the root element, which is must for an xml file, in the sense I am not able to get the logic to identify the root element

Comment: @darren.. I cant use parse generators.. My project is to build a basic xml parser. I know there are many parsers available but I have to design one on my own,a simple one.

Comment: Hi guys.. I have a small doubt. Creating an XML parser is a small thing or a big thing? My boss says its very easy. I am just confused. He says its a piece of cake and I am not able to do it. I just downloaded the source file of a sample parser and I find it to be like 5000 lines of code.Is that supposed to be easy?

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, the root element is the first element you are going to come across in the XML file.  It should also be the only element at the outermost level.

In XML, elements are strictly nested, so to detect the closing tag for the root element, you are going to need a stack of start tags that you have found so you can properly track that they are all closed properly.  I imagine your algorithm will look something like:

```
get first XML thing
while not end of file and not error
    if thing is a comment or processing instruction or straight text
        ignore it // Let's not get complicated yet!
    else if thing is a start tag
        push the tag on the stack
        if thing is the *first* start tag
            root element
    else if thing is an end tag
        if the stack is empty
            error
        else if it does not match the tag on the top of the stack
            error
        else
            pop the top element from the stack
            if the stack is now empty
                closing tag for root element
    get next XML thing
if no error 
    if stack is empty
        finished OK
    else
        error
```

By the way, that's the easy bit.  If you are going to do this properly, you need to write a tokeniser to give you the XML lexical objects  (e.g. tags, comments, processing instructions, attributes etc) in the first place.

Comment: Hi thanks for the idea.. Can you also tell me something abt the tokeniser thing?

Comment: @holbond: It's the process of analysing a sequence of characters (e.g. a text file) to produce a sequence of tokens that represent the syntactical elements of your language.  A start tag might be a token, for instance.  If you have to write it from scratch, it's normal to use a state transition table.  See here for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Comment: Hii.. I have one slight problem.. what would be the logic if there are single tags in between? Can you please tell me what the logic would be?

Comment: @holbond:  I assume you mean something like `<foo/>`.  That's easy, unless it is the root element, you can simply ignore it.